# Undo commit when Push fails

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

we are using TortoiseGit 
The "commit" saves the changes to the local repository.

When the push fails, the file is still committed to the local repository and TortoiseGit status icon on the file is green.. This is confusing because the developer doesn't know the file in the remote repository is out of sync.

1) Is there any way to directly with the remote repository(like in SVN), when the push fails, the status icon should be  red

or

2) When a push fails, it is possible to undo the local repository commit automatically?

Comment: I'm not a tortoise expert so I can't offer an answer. However, I do have 2 points to make. This will be doable using the command line using a few trigger scripts. More importantly, both your requirements suggest that you're trying to make git work "like SVN" which is a bad idea. There's no need to push after every commit and rolling back a commit if a push fails is not a really meaningful workflow. Committed and pushed are two separate things in git. You should take advantage of that and make your workflow flexible rather than try to cripple git and make it like svn.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the files  colores to judge the git status always;

and when there are errors because of sync the remote rep commits

You should `git pull` firstly and then `git push` your commit(s).

And  you needn't  undo the commit (although you can undo it using `git reset` and `git checkout` )

In the end, Git has different ideas and methods with SVN. Just think in Git, forgive the SVN.